# ReflectionException (-1) Class checkSession does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have a middleware `checkSession` for checking sessions in my Laravel Project. But, while serving the Laravel project using `php artisan serve`, the project is served successfully. But, while using the web application, this error is being thrown `ReflectionException (-1)
Class checkSession does not exist`

I have searched for other answers on SO. But none of them seems to work for my case.

I have also double checked that checkSession class exists in the correct Middleware directory with correct namespace. I am not able to figure why the error is happening. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have missed registering the middleware. After defining the middleware, you should register it to a particular route or a group of routes or for all HTTP requests to your application.

If you don't register a middleware, it won't know on which route the middleware should be activated.

If you want to register the middleware for all the routes in your application, add `checkSession` to the `$middleware` property present in the `/app/Http/Kernel.php` file.

Else, if you want to activate the middleware for certain routes, associate a key to the middleware and add it to the existing middlewares present in the `$routeMiddleware` property in the above-mentioned file.

For e.g. append this to the `$routeMiddleware` variable: `'checkSession' => \App\Http\Middleware\checkSession::class,` Now, you can use this `checkSession` key for associating this middleware with specific routes in your route definition.

I strongly recommend you to read the documentation before implementing. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#registering-middleware)